# How do I get ID of row i just inserted in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Ok so my code looks like this

```
        String sqlString = "INSERT into auditlog(report_name, username, start_datetime, resource_uri, resource_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, reportName);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        preparedStatement.setString(4, uri);
        preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(5, new BigDecimal(0));
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The table has one more field "ID", but that gets auto generated, how do I get that key ? I need to use it as a Foreign Key in the next bit of my code

Comment: ummm... `SELECT ID FROM YourTable`?

Comment: @Doorknob `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM YourTable`

Comment: @Abu so you directly ignore concurrence and get whatever ID you might retrieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

if (generatedKeys.next()) {
    Long id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
}
```

Comment: Will this work ? ____
String generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys().toString();

Comment: No Andre, this returns a `ResultSet` object, you need to retrieve it from `ResultSet`

Comment: I edited my answer. If your id is Long, you get it like this.

Answer (score 3):

`Statement` interface  defines [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) method. But it all **depends on the driver** you use. If the driver implements it, you can retrieve the generated IDs

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to your prepare, and then use [getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) to retrieve it;

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString,      
    PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);  

...

int rownum = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  
ResultSet resultset = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();  
if( rownum != 0 && !resultset.next()) {  
      int version = resultset.getInt(1);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" should do it.  Make sure you do it in the same transaction, of course.

Don't "SELECT MAX(id) FROM ...".  That could easily work fine but get slower and slower as the table grows.

Also, since JDBC coding is nearly all boilerplate coding, write yourself a SqlUtils.getLastInsertId(Connection con) method somewhere, and save yourself some typing!